# Const Char to LPTSTR

Tags: opengl, lptstr

I have looked for similar problems but none are in the context I require. The odd thing with this is that I get this error yet a different project set out in code the same way seems to work perfectly.

I am trying to load images into textures in openGL and have a function which takes in this parameter:

```
GLuint loadTexture(LPTSTR szFileName);
```

I then call it like this:

```
textureLib[0]= loadTexture("texturelib/texture1.bmp");
textureLib[1]= loadTexture("texturelib/texture2.bmp");
textureLib[2]= loadTexture("texturelib/texture3.bmp");
textureLib[3]= loadTexture("texturelib/texture4.bmp");
```

it then says "1>e:\usb\uni work\graphics\coursework\coursework\main.cpp(291): error C2664: 'loadTexture' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [24]' to 'LPTSTR'"

As stated above another program that I have seems to allow it so if there is a way of just fixing it to run it that would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LPTSTR` is either `char*` or `wchar_t*`, depending on whether Unicode macros are set (`UNICODE`, `_UNICODE`). And if you're passing literals to that function, you should not use it (and use `LPCTSTR` instead, which is `const char/wchar_t*`). After you change the signature, use `_T()` or `TEXT()` macro to match the literals to the type, i.e.

```
GLuint loadTexture(LPCTSTR filename);
loadTexture(TEXT("texturelib/texture1.bmp"));
```